# C++ Builder XE OBJ file

Tags: c++builder

I have a C++ Builder XE project with several 3rd party controls.  Some of the 3rd party controls did not have a specific XE package so I wound up taking 2010 and compiling, etc...

After many gyrations, I can get my project to compile but not link.

I get the error:
[ILINK32 Error] Fatal: Unable to open file 'THEMESRV.OBJ'

I'm using LMD VCL tools (http://www.lmdinnovative.com/products/vcl/) where I think this is coming from.  See, in CBuilder 6 project and older version of LMD tools there exists a Themesrv.obj file.  My larger project was to convert from CBuilder6 to XE and in so doing I downloaded the latest 2010 version of LMD's controls; the Builder6 controls would not compile under XE.

Now if I create a brand new XE project and include some of the suspect controls from LMD components, I get clean compiles and links.

I even did silly things like copying the themesrv.obj file into my project's build space only to get reference problems.

Any suggestions on tracking this down?  I'm not explicitly including any LIB or OBJ files in my project manager and I've gone through the project XML file looking for bogus references...

Thoughts/Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With packages/components, it is almost never an .obj file that you really need in this situation. It is either a .lib file or a .bpi file (depending on whether or not you are using static/dynamic linking)

In this case, you appear to already know which set of packages you're dealing with, so you should be able to add the right file/path references to your project. Bpi files should be listed in the packages options, the path to the lib file should be in the Directories and Conditionals->Library paths, you can also explicitly add the .lib to you project, but this should not be necessary)

If you're uncertain about which lib/bpi file(s) to use, tdump can be your ally here. Running tdump on these files should show you a line that says "implements: WHATEVER.obj" for the one(s) you need.

Comment: well, the obj file in question is doesn't seem apart of any controls listed in the IDE's component list.  I went from a Cbuilder6 version of LMD's tools to their CBuilder 2010 version.  One of the apparent changes was the removal of Themes since they can now leverage that in the borland product itself (I guess).  My project loads fine in the IDE with all the components (it didn't before) and it compiles clean just won't link.  It's as if the IDE is somehow thinking I need this OBJ file and what gets me is it's not listed in the linker command line as shown in the property of the project.

Comment: @Eric, an .obj file corresponds to a source file. The way packages/components work is to take all the individual objs and bundle them together. You're looking for the right .lib/.bpi file which contains the .obj file's data. (the linker will stop asking when it finds the .lib/.bpi) You have to make sure that file is either 1) in the Project->Options->Packages->Build with runtime packages listbox(asuming the checkbox is checked) 2) The .lib file can be found on one of the paths listed in Project->Options->Directories and Conditionals->Library path, or 3) the .lib file is added to the project.

Comment: I'm, obviously, aware that an obj file corresponds to a source file.  The source file in question is no longer apart of the new version of the 3rd party component yet CBuilder keeps complaining that it's missing for some reason.  It's an orphaned OBJ file I don't need but don't know how to convince C++ Builder of this!  You'll note I say the problem doesn't exit in new projects.  The OBJ file is not part of the XML project in question either.

Comment: turned out to be a path issue.  Another path higher up the search chain had the subject OBJ file from an old build.... <sigh>